# Display a block in Magento Admin Panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, adminhtml, grid

I am getting error like below

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_addContent() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, boolean given,
```

My indexAction code is like below

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        // instantiate the grid container
        $brandBlock = $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('digitech_brandlogo_adminhtml/brandlogo');

        // Add the grid container as the only item on this page
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_addContent($brandBlock)
            ->renderLayout();
    }
```

In this case my Question is What does it mean by "

```
$brandBlock = $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('digitech_brandlogo_adminhtml/brandlogo');
```

" ??

I would like to know about block and layout structure/arrangement for this.

Answer (score 0):

*`$this->getLayout()`* basically call current page layouts and `createBlock` **create block() at in current page.**

But in your code,you have try to call a block before load layout `$this->loadLayout()`.So you ***should call layout first the add block in layout***

```
/* first load layout */
$this->loadLayout();
/*then inject bloack at page */
 $brandBlock = $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('digitech_brandlogo_adminhtml/brandlogo');
/* using    _addContent add this block at content area */
   $this->_addContent($brandBlock)
    ->renderLayout();
```